# Hermitian solution(s) of Algebraic Riccati equation.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Given $3\times 3$ matrices $A,R,Q$ and $R,Q$ is skew-hermitian

Find (all) hermitian solution(s) of:

$$XRX+A^\dagger X-XA+Q=0$$.

Generally I just need 1 (beautiful) solution.

Comment: Are you sure that there is a solution? In the special case that $A=0$, $R=iI$ ($I$ is the identity operator) and $Q=iT$ with $T$ a positive matrix $X^2$ must be negative so $X$ cannot be Hermitean.

Comment: The question is find the solution if there are any. :D